# How can I get the title of the current hovered element without using (this)?

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

I am displaying content inside of fancybox which doesn't allow me to use (this) when it loads. This means I need to be able to pull the title of the current hovered element and display it without using (this).

Here is what I currently use outside of Fancybox

```
$(function() {
    $('#palette').on('mouseover', 'a', function () {
        $('#PaletteColorName').text("Color: " + this.title);
    });
    $('#palette').on('mouseleave', 'a', function () {
        $('#PaletteColorName').text("Color: ");
    });
});
```

[Current Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheEks/TFGxJ/%20%22JS%20Fiddle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `this` :)

```
$(function() {
    $('#palette').on('mouseover', 'a', function (event) {
        $('#PaletteColorName').text("Color: " + event.target.title);
    });
    $('#palette').on('mouseleave', 'a', function () {
        $('#PaletteColorName').text("Color: ");
    });
});
```

Comment: It's a pleasure. Glad to help.